# Ignore URL in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, url, authentication

I have a Silverlight Business Application, and I have the login Window as first window. After that, the application loads the MainPage.xaml, but when there is something on URL, the application loads the page from the URL... How can I ignore the URL???, because I need that my application goes always to MainPage after login...

Comment: Can you give examples? It is not very clear what is going on.

Comment: After the Login Window, the URl is 'http://localhost:1408/TestPage.aspx#/Home', but if you put 'http://localhost:1408/TestPage.aspx#/Home/Products', the application goes to Products page after login, and I need that the application goes always to Home...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to redirect after a successful login?

```
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Hi Erno, it sounds good, but I have a problem, how can I access to NavigationService from an UserControl, which contains the Login Form???

Comment: @Miguel Ochoa, Try to cast the parent?

Comment: Hi Erno, I solved the problem, I just had to do this:

ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Home", UriKind.Relative));

on the Loaded event in the MainPage, but your answer helped me a lot, thanks